# Executing a non blocking thread in C++

Tags: c++

I have a main program, this main program executes a thread that perform an action until the user triggers a stop. The problem that I have is if I add `th.join()` the main program won't continue until the thread finishes. And If there is no `.join()` the program crashs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <optional>

static bool s_finished = false;

using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

void SendData(int id)
{
    std::cout << "Working thread: " << id << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Started thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    while (!s_finished)
    {
        std::cout << "Working\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }

}

void startRecording(std::optional<int> t)
{

      std::thread th1 (SendData, 1);
     //th1.join();


    std::cout << "[startRecording] Other Task" << std::endl;
}

void stopRecording()
{
    s_finished = true;
    std::cout << "[stopRecording] Other Task" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start Program!" << std::endl;

    startRecording();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);

    stopRecording();

    return 0;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: "if I add th.join() the main program won't continue until the thread finishes" - Of course. That's what `join()` is *for* (wait until the thread terminates).

Comment: But I don't want that. If I remove the `join()` the program crash

Comment: If you don't `join` the thread, but just terminate the process, you have no Idea what state the thread is in and a crash is likely. You need to build in a mechanism to tell your thread to stop what it is doing and make your thread react to that and then `join` it, knowing that it will terminate shortly (in a well defined state, because you just told it to), *then* terminate the process. Yes, multithreaded code is *difficult* to get right.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Actually, a crash is _guaranteed_ - take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread

Comment: @Asteroid To be pedantic, [std::set_terminate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate) exists..

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, it does, [but it cannot help you avoid a crash](http://eel.is/c++draft/exception.terminate#terminate.handler-2).

Comment: You can send a signal to the thread.  The thread can exit in its signal handler, so then you can join

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Joining a thread will cause the program to stop until that thread is finished, and that's why the program blocks. We have to call join() eventually so that all child threads finish before the program exits, but we shouldn't call join until we need the child thread to be finished.

The simplest way to get the program to work is to return the thread from `startRecording`, so that we have control of it inside `main`. Then, we join the thread at the end of `main`, after we call `stopRecording`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <optional>
#include <atomic>

// (1) This needs to be atomic to avoid data races
std::atomic<bool> s_finished { false };

using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

void SendData(int id)
{
    std::cout << "Working thread: " << id << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Started thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    while (!s_finished)
    {
        std::cout << "Working\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }

}

std::thread startRecording(std::optional<int> t)
{
    std::thread th1 (SendData, 1);

    std::cout << "[startRecording] Other Task" << std::endl;

    // (2) We return the thread so we can join it in main:
    return th1;
}

void stopRecording()
{
    s_finished = true;
    std::cout << "[stopRecording] Other Task" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start Program!" << std::endl;

    // (3) We save the thread to a variable named 'worker' 
    // so we can join it later. I also added an input to startRecording b/c it needed one
    std::thread worker = startRecording(std::optional<int>{1});

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);

    stopRecording();

    // (4) Join here, at the end
    worker.join(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Now, the program prints the expected output, then exits without problems:

```
Start Program!
[startRecording] Other Task
Working thread: 1
Started thread id: 139985258444544
Working
Working
Working
Working
Working
[stopRecording] Other Task
```

I marked my changes with (1), (2), (3), and (4) in the comments of the code. They're pretty small, and if you have questions about any of them I can provide additional explanation!

### Addendum - using global variables when the signature of `startRecording` can't be changed

In general, it's best to avoid global variables, but I know it's not always possible to do so. if `startRecording`'s signature can't be changed, we can't return a thread, so the thread has to be accessed globally. Here's how to do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <optional>
#include <atomic>

// (1) This needs to be atomic to avoid data races
std::atomic<bool> s_finished { false };

// (2) we initialize this in startRecording
std::thread worker;

using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

void SendData(int id)
{
    std::cout << "Working thread: " << id << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Started thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    while (!s_finished)
    {
        std::cout << "Working\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }

}

void startRecording(std::optional<int> t)
{
    // (3) worker gets initialized, and thread starts
    worker = std::thread(SendData, 1);

    std::cout << "[startRecording] Other Task" << std::endl;
}

void stopRecording()
{
    s_finished = true;
    std::cout << "[stopRecording] Other Task" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start Program!" << std::endl;

    startRecording(std::optional<int>{1});

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);

    stopRecording();

    // (4) Join here, at the end
    worker.join(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get this warnings
` main.cpp:40:12: warning: moving a local object in a return statement prevents copy elision
main.cpp:40:12: note: remove std::move call here`
Why did you added `std::move`?

Comment: What do you think of doing `th1.detach();` ? I can not change stopRecording declaration

Comment: I added `std::move` because thread variables can't be copied but they can be moved. In this case, adding `std::move` was a mistake because values returned from a function are automatically moved, and in many cases the compiler can eliminate the move altogether via copy elision.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `th1.detach()`, because then you have no way of knowing if the thread finished, and if the program exits before the thread finishes it could still cause problems.

Comment: I updated my answer to get rid of the `std::move` call, and that should get rid of the error

Comment: If you don't want to return the thread because you can't change the declaration, would it be possible to make it a global variable? I could update the answer to show how that'd work

Comment: That would we very helpful.

Comment: I updated the question to show how it works using a global variable!